# No login window display on Debian

Tags: debian, login, troubleshooting

I am using `Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)` operating system in my institute. Yesterday I put a MATLAB program on a different machine from mine using `ssh` to run, which takes hours. Today morning when I came, I cannot log-in to my machine since there is no log-in window. It was just showing a background with the Debian logo.

*What should I do?* This is happening to me on different occasions. What normally I do is shutdown and restart.

Comment: Have you tried opening one of the consoles? Ctrl+Alt+F1 (or F2, or F3,...F6), simultaneously. Do you have access to one of these?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae : Yes. It doesnot work at all.

Comment: Did you try to ssh into it?

Comment: No I did'nt tried that. I had no access to other machine at that time.

Comment: But then your problem is that your machine *crashed* (in some sense, it need not be kernel panic). Next time this happens, try the numlock key , which is processed on a lower level then the other keys.If numlock led changes, it means the kernel/processor is still responding to input and the problem is likely in an application. Also, when it freezes, are any keyboard indicators flashing?  That would indicate a kernel panic.

Comment: OK I will try that.

Comment: In any case, try running an `fsck`.